# Java ObservableList filtering with predicate with Strings

Tags: java, list, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have an observable list, I tried to filter it by different predicates.

I have nested objects on which I do filtering.

Here is the first pojo

```
public Class Transaction  {
    private String name; 
    private Account account ; 
    private BigDecimal ammout ; 
}


public class Account{
    private String nameBank;
    private String number;
    private BigDecimal balance;
}
```

I have used Java 8 stream API to do filtering, it doesn't work for String, but it works perfectly for balance and other types.

Here is how i do filter my list:

```
public void findByBankName(String bankName) {
ObservableList<Transaction> transactionList = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList();
 return transactionList.stream()
                .filter(t ->
                        t.getAccount().getnameBank().Contains(bankName) )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Instead it work when i do 
// .filter(t ->  t.getAccount().getBalance().doubleValue() > 0 )
}
```

So, what's the issue with my code ?

Comment: a) Your code doesn't compile. b) What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is the filter not working for strings but it works when i compare with numbers. I have update my code

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does your computer grow legs and walk out the door?

Comment: my transactionList  is not filtred based on the String provided "bankName".

Comment: `getnameBank()` returns a `String`. In Java, `String` doesn't have a `Contains` method. What is it supposed to do? Is it only a typo on `.contains()` ?

Comment: transactionList is empty in your example... So filtering will just return an empty list.

Comment: Methods declared `void` can’t return a value. Another issue is you blatant ignorance towards upper case and lower case. You can’t declare a `class` by writing `Class` and you can’t invoke the method `contains` by writing `Contains`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just hand-typed the code in this question, thats why there are compilation errors. I refactored your classes (with some assumptions).

Account class

```
public class Account{
    private String nameBank;
    private String number;
    private BigDecimal balance;

    public String getNameBank() {
        return nameBank;
    }

    public void setNameBank(String nameBank) {
        this.nameBank = nameBank;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

Transaction class

```
public class Transaction  {
    private String name;
    private Account account ;
    private BigDecimal ammout ;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmmout() {
        return ammout;
    }

    public void setAmmout(BigDecimal ammout) {
        this.ammout = ammout;
    }
}
```

I created this class and named as TransactionsManager

```
public class TransactionsManager {
    private final List<Transaction> transactionsList;

    public TransactionsManager(List<Transaction> transactionsList) {
        this.transactionsList = Collections.unmodifiableList(transactionsList);
    }

    public List<Transaction> findByBankName(String bankName) {
        return transactionsList.stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getAccount().getNameBank().contains(bankName))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this helps!!